# How can i change default android NFC event?

Tags: android, triggers, nfc, android-4.4-kitkat

I write application which using NFC capability.
I use 4.4.4 Android device to test them.

It's my part of AndroidMainfest :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data  android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My problem is: When approaching device to nfc tag, device open default nfc application "Trigger" (when it's unistalled goes to Google Play) I have installed others nfc apps but select app dialog app isn't appear ), and I'cant catch event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger application put a `NdefRecord` a specific mime-type, so Android system check if one application is available to open this tag with specific mime-type.

Please read this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ndef

So if you want to catch tags from Trigger, you have to add filters to your `activity` in `AndroidManifest`. For instance, something like this:

```
     <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/scriptlet"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-nfc-taskl"/>
            <data android:mimeType="x/nfctl"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/nfctl"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/nfctlat"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/nfctlfree"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="x/nfctl-s"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/nfctl"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```